# Ajax request issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a html form to make an order in a shop by clicking a button called `Order`.(button_id="order")
At the button click event i have performed a ajax request to a page(itemOrder_php2.php) which sends some data in the form to that mentioned page. It's working correctly. But the problem is ajax request is not functioning when two or more users order at the same time. Please help me to work with multiple ajax requests. Thank you! here is my code.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#order").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();                    
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "itemOrder_php2.php",
            data: { selectedItem: $("#selectedItem").val(), sizeUnit: $("#sizeUnit").val(), quantity: $("#quantity").val(), value: x, lSize : $("#lSize").val(), lPrice : $("#lPrice").val() },
            success:function(result){  
      $("#orderResult").html(result);               
    }});  
  });
});
```

Comment: Define `not working`. is it returning some error? Did you check the console?

Comment: What do you mean by 'at the same time'? Two users on different browsers?

Comment: not working means it's not performing the button click event at least once..

Comment: actually it is impossible to use this form among several users at the same time... when two or more people logged in that button click event is not functioning to all users... Problem should be exactly with the ajax request...Can you just give me a solution with multiple ajax request method? thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Handle the click event with document on...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#order',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();                    

    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "itemOrder_php2.php",
            data: { selectedItem: $("#selectedItem").val(), sizeUnit: $("#sizeUnit").val(), quantity: $("#quantity").val(), value: x, lSize : $("#lSize").val(), lPrice : $("#lPrice").val() },
            success:function(result){  
      $("#orderResult").html(result);               
    }});  
  });
});
```

Comment: What does event delegation have to do with his problem?